# How to manage AutoRefresh of AccessToken for Microsoft Graph SDK (Using Google oauth2 library For Managing Authentication)

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the AccessToken, Refresh Token Available and stored in the database against each user authenticated and authorized.
I am using GraphSDK for Java for calling the APIs. To Instantiate a **GraphServiceClient** object i have to pass **IAuthenticationProvider** instance.
What i want to understand is how do i instantiate this IAuthenticationProvider class so that while making the api call ,if the access token is detected to be expired ,it internally uses refresh token to get a fresh access token like what happens in GoogleCredential class of google oauth library.
I am using Google auth library for managing oauth2 authentication. I know there is **com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential** Class in the library which does manage this autorefresh but how can i use this class in the GraphSDK.
I can also switch to any other library or native API calls if the solution handles autorefresh of access token by using refresh token.
Can i Use MSAL4J for my use case?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where you ever able to get a solution?

Comment: i used custom implementation to identify token expiry and renewal.